# How to play a song with Audio Queue API in order to find the Accurate timings of the beat of the song

Tags: nsdate, nstimer, core-audio, audioqueue, audio-player

Now I am working on a musical project in which i need accurate timings.I already used NSTimer,NSdate,but iam geting delay while playing  the beats(beats i.e **tik tok**)So i have decided to use Audio Queue API to play my sound file present in the main bundle that is of .wav format, Its been 2 weeks i am struggling with this, Can anybody please help me out of this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use uncompressed sounds and a single Audio Queue, continuously running.  Don't stop it between beats.  Instead mix in raw PCM samples of each Tock sound (etc.) starting some exact number of samples apart.  Play silence (zeros) in between.  That will produce sub-millisecond accurate timing.